# 504 error in nginx +php-fpm :  post request

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I have a test server with nginx and php-fpm.

Pages on the site are opening correctly, but when I want send POST request for example an "authorize on site" I get "504 Gateway Time-out error".
Nginx and php-fpm are configured with default settings.

What could be the reason for the 504 ?

Comment: The best way to tackle this problem is to look into `nginx-error.log`.

Comment: Did you resolve this? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be a pretty common problem, as shown on the past at StackOverflow:

- [How do I prevent a Gateway Timeout with Nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561946/how-do-i-prevent-a-gateway-timeout-with-nginx)
- [Django site on Nginx+FastCGI goes (504 gateway timeout)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466963/django-site-on-nginxfastcgi-goes-504-gateway-timeout)
- [nginx error “ 504 Gateway Timeout”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642168/nginx-error-504-gateway-timeout)

Anyway, for your specific problem I'd say the answer lies in the PHP-FPM configuration. Maybe you should check your php-fpm.conf (if you've got PHP5-FPM, you should check `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` or `/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf`) and set this parameter:

```
request_terminate_timeout = 30s
```

Changing that to lower or higher value could be useful too if things don't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also handle this on the nginx side if nginx is timing out when you are doing your fastcgi pass by using these directives in the stanza with the fastcgi_pass:

```
fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
fastcgi_read_timeout 60;
```

Those would set the connect and response timeout to 60 seconds before nginx would give you the 504.